# Не распознает наличие текста в поле

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, написал `javascript` проверку `textarea` перед отправление, но даже  если информация введена в ее он все равно выдает ошибку.Вот сам код...

```
var ID = $(".reply_id").attr("id");

var reply= $("#replytext"+ID).val();
var dataString = 'reply='+ reply + '&tid=' + ID;

if($.trim(reply).length==0)
{
   alert("Please Enter reply Text");
}
```

А вот код-пример верстки самого поля

```
<div class="reply_box" id="replybox3">   
    <div class="reply_id" id="3"></div>
    <div>
        <textarea rel="3" id="replytext3" class="reply" name="reply" maxlength="140"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Подскажите в чем проблема ?(Даже при заполненном выдает please enter и тд и тп)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Непонятно, когда вы получаете значение `textarea`, по идее код верный.

Я накатал пример: http://jsfiddle.net/YpsRy/

```
$(function() { 
    $("#replytext3").on('keyup', function() {
        var reply= $(this).val();

        if($.trim(reply).length==0) {
           alert("Please Enter reply Text");
        }   
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, вроде все что нужно, еще маленький вопрос, а как сделать так что бы при нажатии клавиши интер в этой текстарее срабатывал скрипт ?Заранее спасибо!

Comment: if (e.keyCode == 13) {
   //...
}
Соответственно переменная содержит свойства события, получают её из функции обработчика первым параметром: http://javascript.ru/tutorial/events/properties